# Visual Studio "Registers" Window- show register content as decimal?

Tags: visual-studio

In the Visual Studio debugging window "Registers", is there a way to display the register contents as decimal?

(I am using 2013)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, regardless:

Using Visual Studio 2015 (May be different in your version), go to Debug > Windows > Watch > Watch 1.

In the window that opens, type in the names of the registers you want to see in decimal, and then hit Enter.

[image]

The data listed under "Value" on the left shows the decimal value of the register. This can also be used to watch variables in the same manner.

Comment: This does not work for me in Visual Studio 2019: attempting to input the register names in the watch window just results in an error saying the identifier is not valid in the context (like it was an undeclared variable).